# If condition inside thymeleaf-html is not working properly

Tags: html, if-statement, thymeleaf

This is thymeleaf code

here 2 th:if conditions are checked and 2 headers are visible in the webpage

here i want to visible only true conditioned statement  header to visible in the webpage

the values for Users a List values

the condition is there is any loggedusers the header is sellerhome and there is no loggedusers the list is null so the homepage header is shows on the webpage

```
<div th:each="s,pStat : ${Users} "> 
<div th:if="${s ==null}"  th:unless="${pStat.index > 0}">
    <header  th:include="../templates/homeTemplate :: header" id="header">
    </header> 
</div> 
<div  th:else="${s != null} "  th:unless="${pStat.index > 0}" >
    <header th:include="../templates/SellerTemplate :: header" id="header">
    </header>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: You should try to express yourself a little better because the question is very hard to read :)

Comment: @geoand i know that but my language is very bad

Comment: I understand, but people probably can't figure out what it is you want to do :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I have understood correctly what it is you are trying to do, use the following code:

```
<div th:if="${#lists.isEmpty(Users)}">
    <header  th:include="../templates/homeTemplate :: header" id="header">
    </header> 
</div> 
<div th:unless="${#lists.isEmpty(Users)}">
    <header th:include="../templates/SellerTemplate :: header" id="header">
    </header>
</div>
```

`#lists` is a Thymeleaf Utility Object that contains common methods used for processing lists.
For more details see the section "Expression Utility Objects" in the [Thymeleaf](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/html/Using-Thymeleaf.html) documentation.

Also note that `lists.isEmpty` checks whether the list is null or empty, so it's save to use without the null check

Comment: Hi it's working but i want to know the value lists is from where?

Comment: i change list to boolean the question is here   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23903277/how-to-set-modelattribute-boolean-value-inside-html  this is working correctly but i want this condition in another place plese help