# how to set @modelattribute boolean value inside html

Tags: java, html, thymeleaf, modelattribute

the code shows below

the Users value from @Modelattribute is boolean an how to set this condition

```
 <div  th:each="s: ${Users}"> 
        <div  th:if="${s == true"  >
            <header th:include="../templates/SellerTemplate :: header" id="header">
            </header>
        </div>
        <div th:if="${s != true}" >
            <header  th:include="../templates/homeTemplate :: header" id="header">
            </header> 
        </div> 

    </div>
```

the @Modelattribue

```
public boolean users ;
@ModelAttribute("Users")
public boolean getloggeduser() {
 if(securityDAO.getLoggedUserAccount()!= null) { 
    users=true;
     }
 else{ 
     users=false;
 } 
    return users;
}
```

the main problem is how to set the attribute value to th:each or any other statement are available? please share your answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that you are looking for something like this:

```
<div th:if="${Users == true}"  >
   <header th:include="../templates/SellerTemplate :: header" id="header">
   </header>
</div>
<div th:if="${Users == false}" >
   <header  th:include="../templates/homeTemplate :: header" id="header">
   </header> 
</div>
```

You should only use `th:each` for lists or arrays, there is no point using it for other types.

Comment: here th:if="${s == true}" the s value coming from where or s   assigns  value where

Comment: There is one more issue when user loggedout the boolean value doesn't change in modelattribute

Comment: That is a totally different issue, probably has something to do with how you are using Spring Security

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54590/discussion-between-prasanth-ar-and-geoand).